# how to show same data when back/reload button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have form.html page and when user hits next button it goes to some other page so i want user to be able to edit the data which he has entered before in form.html. But when user hits back button my controller is initialized again and data is lost. I know ways to shared data between different controller but i don't know how to show that data on my view

Comment: You can try saving the data using [https://redux.js.org/](https://redux.js.org/) or [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as this question stands, without any code, its hard to provide any more help.

Comment: For navigation alone, it's enough to store it in a **service**, which you can inject in any controller and share your data. But if you want to save it after a page refresh, then it has to be stored elsewhere. This can be your back-end (database) or front-end (`localStorage`)

Comment: I am having various checkboxes in my form.html so if i get ids of the checkbox which was checked using services then how can i show the checkboxes checked

Comment: @vishalgwalani bind checkboxes to some shared **array**, e.g. `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="array[$index]">`, if it looks like `$scope.array = [false, false, true, false];`